# How's Mango Languages Latin Pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, latin

So through my library I've gained access to Mango Languages language courses and I've taken on learning Latin. When trying to keep my pronunciation as close to the examples as possible, though, I feel I'm almost getting an American accent (my first language is Swedish).

I know this question is hard to answer because, firstly, you need access to Mango Languages, and then you need to know how Latin is "supposed" to sound, but I'm wondering if I shouldn't try so hard speaking exactly like the examples, but rather focus more on learning words and grammar.

Also, I took a listen to one Latin news radio program from Germany and one from Finland. Their pronunciation was very much influenced by their mother tongue. With Latin, having been the lingua franca for a long time through history, is it generally more acceptable to have an accent? Is there even a correct way to speak Latin?

Comment: While there is *pronuntiatio restituta*, which is now standard for academic Classical Latin, there is no correct, "accentless" way to speak Latin.